# Why the SUSY particles of fermions have spin 0 but not 1?

Tags: quantum-spin, field-theory, supersymmetry, beyond-the-standard-model

As the supersymmetric particles have spin which differs by half, why cant the superpartners have a spin = 1. Why does it always have to be 0?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Supersymmetry: spin of the superpartners](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/445277/supersymmetry-spin-of-the-superpartners)